# How to fix exception "DataflowAssert requires that JUnit and Hamcrest be linked in"?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When running a Dataflow unittest that uses DataflowAssert I get the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: DataflowAssert requires that JUnit and Hamcrest be linked in.
```

What dependencies do I need to add to my pom file to fix this exception?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following dependencies to your pom file to link in the required libraries

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```